# MS-Access: Split content on delimiter and join with other table

Tags: ms-access, join, ms-access-2007

I am using **MS-Access 2007** and need to make a query.
I cannot modify the architecture to achieve the required result.
I need to split and join the mainTable's "RelatedMaster" (comma separated IDs) to the "Name" field (as comma separated Names in the result) in masterTable.

**Table 1** : masterTable
**ID**    **Name**
1        N1
2        N2
3        N3

**Table 2** : mainTable
**ID**    **Name**    **RelatedMaster**
1        M1        1,2
2        M2        1,3
3        M3        2,3

**Required Result** : resultQuery
**ID**    **Name**    **RelatedMaster**
1        M1        N1,N2
2        M2        N1,N3
3        M3        N2,N3

Please guide on how can i solve the problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you realize at this point, it is bad design, but you can use a helper function:

```
Public Function GetNs(ByVal MasterIds As String) As Variant

    Dim MasterValues As Variant
    Dim Item As Integer

    MasterValues = Split(MasterIds, ",")
    ' Lookup Name one by one.
    For Item = LBound(MasterValues) To UBound(MasterValues)
        MasterValues(Item) = DLookup("[Name]", "[Table 1]", "ID = " & MasterValues(Item) & "")
    Next

    GetNs = Join(MasterValues, ",")

End Function
```

Of course, for a large Table 1, you would open it as a recordset and find the values.

Comment: I know the architecture is not good but i was originally designed like that by the architect and now at this point either we can go for a function in access or similar code in front end. Thank you, it worked i was just hoping if we could somehow use split and joins to achieve this!